# LDAP Module - Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ldap_authentication_init() appears

Tags: authentication-authorization

I have a site with Drupal 7.41 and LDAP module version 7.x-2.0-beta8. My goal is to connect my drupal site with an Active Directory account. 
After I installed LDAP module i saw a error message: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ldap_authentication_init() (line 223 of  [... ] ldap/ldap_authentication/ldap_authentication.module) 
But i thought that was a part of Module. When i configure and test my module, this error message still appears. The stack of test is:

```
            sid = empresa.cl
            numeric_sid = 1
            name = empresa.cl
            status = 1
            ldap_type = default
            address = XX.XXX.X.XXX
            port = 389
            tls = 0
            followrefs = 0
            bind_method = 2
            basedn = Array ( [0] => ou=chile,dc=empresa,dc=cl )
            binddn =
            user_dn_expression = empresa//%username
            user_attr = samaccountname
            account_name_attr =
            mail_attr = mail
            mail_template =
            picture_attr =
            unique_persistent_attr =
            unique_persistent_attr_binary = 0
            ldap_to_drupal_user =
            testing_drupal_username = nombre
            testing_drupal_user_dn = CN=nombre, OU=chile, DC=empresa, DC=cl
            grp_unused = 0
            grp_object_cat =
            grp_nested = 0
            grp_user_memb_attr_exists = 0
            grp_user_memb_attr =
            grp_memb_attr =
            grp_memb_attr_match_user_attr =
            grp_derive_from_dn = 0
            grp_derive_from_dn_attr =
            grp_test_grp_dn =
            grp_test_grp_dn_writeable =
            search_pagination = 0
            search_page_size = 1000
```

Any possible suggestion or advice for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This message disapears when i add data in a 'Authorization Tab' In a email section and I select a "LDAP Server Type" (This option belongs to LDAP server's configuration from Server tab) such as Active Directory.

Thank, you Anyway